# navier-stokes equations in semi-discrete form

Tags: navier-stokes, reduced-order-modelling

Can someone point me to where the Navier-Stokes equations in 2D, both compressible and incompressible are written in semi-discrete form? I'm doing reduced order modelling and I need to write them down in the form

$$
\frac{d\mathbf{x}}{dt} = f(\mathbf{x},t,\mu)
$$

Where $\mu$ is some parameter and $\mathbf{x}$ is a high-dimensional vector containing velocities and pressures at all nodes in the mesh and $t$ is time.

I can write Burgers' equation in 2D in semi-discrete form; but with Navier-Stokes I'm confused about what to do with the pressure term. In incompressible Navier-Stokes we solve a linear system for the pressure and I'm not sure about how to include that in the form I wrote above.

I'm confused because in incompressible Navier-Stokes the time-derivative appears only in the velocity and, in the only algorithm I'm familiar with, the [pressure projection algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_method_(fluid_dynamics)) there is a linear equation for the pressure. These steps mean that I can't see how to write the Navier-Stokes equations in the form I need.

Comment: If you have a PDE and you discretize it in space then you'll end up with the desired form (method of lines). What is the difficulty applying this to incompressible Navier-Stokes equation?

Comment: 1) There is a time derivative only on the velocity term, not pressure. So, I'm not sure how to march the pressure in time.   2) I'm only familiar with the pressure projection algorithm for INS. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_method_(fluid_dynamics) . This algorithm has a linear equation to be solved at every time-step. Again, I'm not sure how to put this into the form I require

Comment: Ok, there is a time-evolution PDE for velocity and an algebraic constraint relating velocity and pressure. Probably one can still use the method of lines there, adding an "inversion" step in the RHS. Can you add your equations to the question statement? There are different forms of NS equations, it would help to see explicitly what you have in mind.

Comment: You can write the incompressible equations as a single evolution equation via the Leray Projection (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leray_projection). However, this is almost never done in numerical methods. The exact semi-discrete form of the equations will be different depending on the choice of ROM, projection method, etc. For compressible flow, the choice of variables becomes another choice depending on your ROM (velocity, density, pressure vs. velocity, specific volume, temperature vs. others). More specificity on your ROM and desired application is needed to provide better answers.

Comment: @whpowell96 Thank you. Let me think a bit more and get back to you. I'm very new to Navier-Stokes.

Comment: @whpowell96 What do you think of https://hal.science/hal-03215118/document ? Could equation 3b be thought of as a time-stepping equation for the pressure?

Comment: Yes, I think that is basically what they are doing. Different numerical algorithms handle it in different ways. For instance, the pressure can be obtained from a Poisson equation with the velocity in the RHS (see the last section here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson%27s_equation) and some algorithms time step velocity then solve the Poisson equation for pressure, so the time stepping in the pressure variable isn't explicit, which makes sense, because no time evolution of the pressure field is prescribed by the equations.

Comment: @whpowell96 Thanks. Have you used this artificial compressibility algorithm before? Do you know how it performs in practice?